# Animate text for landing page

Tags: css, html, css-animations

Is there a way i can easily achieve this type of animated text with  html on my landing page

[image]

Comment: Maybe yes, or with Jquery

Comment: This link will help you http://codepen.io/hi-im-si/pen/DHoup

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is :)

```js
var messages = ["Be", "Up to Speed", "Up to", "Up"],
    counter = 0,
    target = document.getElementById("message");

setInterval(function(){ 
  
  target.innerHTML = messages[counter];
  counter++;
  
  if( counter >= messages.length ) {
    counter = 0;
  }

}, 300);
```

```css
body {
  font: bold 1em sans-serif;
}
#message {
  box-shadow: .125em 0 0 0 rgba(128,128,128,.3);
  color: MediumAquamarine;
  padding-right: .125em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1>You too can... <span id="message"></span></h1>
```